# Tool for taking a bunch of data and guessing its statistical distribution?

Tags: statistics, curve-fitting, goodness-of-fit

If I have a large sample of data (a vector of 10000 numbers or so), is there some tool that will look at the data and try to fit a number of common statistical distributions to the data and report on how good a fit each one is? If I have to specify the list of possible distributions myself, that's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for Statistics tools ... 
R would probably be the first choice - have a look at: www.r-project.org
Grab RStudio as an IDE install package Deducer and off you go with your analysis. 
Ah, and by the way it's all Open-Source / Freeware ...

Greetings, Walter

Comment: Do you know of any R package for guessing distributions?

Comment: Maybe this paper can lead the way http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf

Comment: Or you could also check out glnm (Generalized nonlinear regression models) package on http://www.commanster.eu/rcode.html (Jim Lindsay's R page). There is a function "fit.dist" there that maybe will do some of the things you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, those suggestions both look like good possibilities. I'll check them out.